# How to use Katalon Script in existing browser

Tags: javascript, selenium, katalon-studio

i'm writing a script in Katalon and now I'm stuck.
When using the Chrome Add-On of Katalon I can press play at the automation process starts in my already existing browser window. In this browser I'm already logged in to my destination URL.
If I open the script with Katalon Studio, a new browser window opens which has a clear user profile, so I would have to login.

How do I tell Katalon Studio to open my existing browser window with my loaded user profile, so I'm already logged in when it opens?

Best regards

Marc

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

Tools like katalon are made to run after working hours in their final form,so i am almost sure you can't open the test in your already open browser..
That's kind of logical if you think about the point of testing..you have to start from scratch .
Just code : 
open browser ,
navigate to url ,
set text for both username and password , 
and lastly click the login button .

Answer (score 0):

I think it is hard to execute test on opening browser because any automation tool need the control on the browser which is started by webdriver. 
It may helps if you start test from the openning browser started by the tool. I found some info at: https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/Execute+test+from+specific+step. Hope that it help.